Convert `(String, Int)...` variadic parameter function to Dictionary for ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral
I have objects that are currently initialized via one-parameter init functions that take an Array or Dictionary.
I've realized that I can use ExpressibleByArrayLiteral and ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral instead. But I believe I'll still need the non-literal initializers as well, perhaps until Passing an array to a function with variable number of args in Swift is implemented.
struct ArrayStruct: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
    typealias ArrayLiteralElement = Int
    
    let array: [Int]
    
    init(array: [Int]) {
        self.array = array
    }
    
    init(arrayLiteral elements: Int...) {
        self.init(array: elements) // ok
    }
}

struct DictStruct: ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral {
    typealias Key = String
    typealias Value = Int
    
    let dict: [String : Int]
    
    init(dict: [String : Int]) {
        self.dict = dict
    }
    
    init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (String, Int)...) {
        self.init(dict: elements) // Cannot convert value of type '(String, Int)...' to expected argument type '[String : Int]'
    }
}

I'd like the initializers to both call the same code path, so for the variadic init to call the collection init or vice-versa.
For the array, I can pass the Int... variadic parameter directly to the existing [Int] initializer. Why does this just work for array?
But this doesn't work for the Dictionary. The existing initializer is expecting a [String : Int] dictionary, but the ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral function parameter is a (String, Int)...
Why do these "expressible by Array/Dictionary literal" give you a variadic parameter in the first place, rather than an array/dictionary? It's a literal array... why doesn't it give you an array?
How can I convert (String, Int)... to [String : Int]?

The problem is that there is no "obvious" conversion from a list of key-value pairs to a Dictionary. You must decide how to deal with duplicate keys. Are they a programming error, causing an crash? Do you take the first one? The last one? Combine them somehow? It's up to you to decide and Swift supports all of these approaches.
For example, to crash the program if the keys are not unique (this is not a bad idea for literals), you would write this:
init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (String, Int)...) {
    let dict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: elements)
    self.init(dict: dict)
}

Alternately, to take the last element for a given key, you would write this:
init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (String, Int)...) {
    let dict = Dictionary(elements, uniquingKeysWith: { _, second in second })
    self.init(dict: dict)
}

But you could also accumulate the sum of all duplicate keys:
init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (String, Int)...) {
    let dict = Dictionary(elements, uniquingKeysWith: +)
    self.init(dict: dict)
}


The reason the Dictionary Literal constructor parameter is a (String, Int)... sequence of keys and values rather than a dictionary is that a Dictionary Literal can be declared in your codebase with duplicate keys. Duplicate keys are not allowed in a Dictionary, so you must handle them.
If you are sure there are no duplicate keys in your Dictionary Literal,  init(uniquekeyswithvalues: is the best way to create the Dictionary (but crashes if duplicate keys are found).

You use this initializer to create a dictionary when you have a sequence of key-value tuples with unique keys. Passing a sequence with duplicate keys to this initializer results in a runtime error. If your sequence might have duplicate keys, use the Dictionary(_:uniquingKeysWith:) initializer instead.

In the current version of Xcode, normal Dictionary Literals like [String : Int] receive warnings when they contain duplicate keys. This is nice and greatly reduces the potential crash in uniquekeyswithvalues:. Unfortunately, the same duplicate keys warning is not given to your own custom classes that are made ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral.
struct DictStruct: ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral {
    typealias Key = String
    typealias Value = Int
    
    let dictionary: [String : Int]
    
    init(_ dictionary: [String : Int]) {
        self.dictionary = dictionary
    }
    
    init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (String, Int)...) {
        self.init(Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: elements)) // Crashes if duplicate keys are found in literal
    }
    
    static func testDuplicate() -> Self {
        // Dictionary literal of type '[String : Int]' has duplicate entries for string literal key 'duplicate'. Duplicate key declared here
        let dupe: [String : Int]   = ["duplicate":1, "duplicate":2, "duplicate": 3]

        // No warning when type is the custom struct rather than [String : Int]
        let dupeStruct: DictStruct = ["duplicate":1, "duplicate":2, "duplicate": 3]
        
        return dupeStruct
    }
}

